# CSS Selector :almost-empty?

Tags: html, css, pseudo-class

I'm aware that the `:empty` pseudo-class will select all elements with no children, but I want to only select elements with text-nodes as children.

I have a bottom-border on my hyperlinks that're a different color than the text, but this is a problem because the hyperlinked images are also getting this underline.

I've tried `a *:not(*){ border-bottom-width: 0; }` in an attempt to fix this, but it didn't work. Is there a way to select `a` tags with only text-nodes for children?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just using jQuery. I don't believe it's possible with just CSS right now.

```
jQuery('document').ready(function(){
    jQuery("a").each(function(){
        if(this.children.length !== 0)
            this.style.borderBottomWidth='0';
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem correctly, you are trying to keep your hyperlinked images from being underlined.  If so, why not do something like: `a img { text-decoration:none }`?

**Edit:** If its the links on img tags you don't want underlined, apply a class to those links with `text-decoration:none`

Comment: because the img won't be underlined, but the `<a>` link will be

Comment: That's not feasible. It's Wordpress, and we're developing this for a group of people who won't know how to put the links in a specific class. Also, there's already a `text-decoration: none;` on the `<a>` tags and `<img />` tags. The problem is that there's a bottom border.

Comment: @user1813212 Well I don't know what to tell you about your users except try and educate them.  CSS classes are about as straightforward as it gets IMHO.  But you could also apply a class that removes the bottom border.

Answer (score 1):

**NEW ANSWER:**

If you want a border under the image, but not the text do this:

```
a img { border-bottom: 1px solid #000; }
a:emtpy { border: none; }
```

If you want the opposite (border under the text but not the image) do this:

```
a:empty { border-bottom: 1px solid #000; }
a img { border: none; }
```

**OLD ANSWER:**

If it's just a problem with images that are wrapped in a tags, try:

```
a img { border-bottom: none; }
```

Comment: the underline is on **link**, not on image

Comment: Your updated answer doesn't work. There's a text-node in the `<a>` tag that keeps it from being selected by the `:empty` pseudo-class.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a crazy selector, why not hide the border with a negative margin:

```
a img {
  margin-bottom: -6px;
}
```

[Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/utBzh)

Comment: Some of the linked images have transparent backgrounds.

Comment: Could you set a white background for the `img`, or would that look bad?

Comment: I could, but different images would need different background colors, and some may even be parts of gradients. I'd like to avoid it if possible, but this may have to be what I do if there are no other reasonable answers.

Answer (score 0):

When the **ONLY CHILD** of `<a>` is not an `img` ...

```
a:only-child:not(img)
{
    border-bottom-width: 1;
}
```

Comment: It seems this should work, but it doesn't. I don't think a text-node is recognized as a child except with the `:empty` pseudo-class, which is making me start to think this is impossible without Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be accomplished because of the way `border` property is applied and rendered outside the top-most box of your anchor - effectively the only way to achieve such an effect with a border would be to negate the property. Sometimes it coult be visually acceptable to use a bottom border in a background colour to overlay over that of of your anchor's - an unreliable practice to be frowned upon. Maybe the effect could be simulated with filters, but I wouldn't count on it being sufficiently well-supported cross-browser.

What I propose is going back to the `text-decoration` property *while still maintaining a different, independent underline colour` - a neat approach overall, but not without the overhead of an additional element:

```
<style>
.fancy-underline { color:blue; text-decoration:underline; } 
.fancy-underline a { color:black; text-decoration:none; }
</style>
<span class="fancy-underline"><a href="#">I am a fancy link
  <img src="//placekitten.com/30/30/" /> with an image in the middle of it
</a></span>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ovfiddle/TwmmF/3/